# thread local storage macosx

Tags: thread-local-storage

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html

Documents __thread

yet my g++ complains that __thread is not supported on my arch (Leopard on Macbookpro).

Why is this? And how do I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that page is just an Apple stylesheet slapped on the standard GCC manual. Notice the `.so` instead of `.dylib` in Mac OS X.

So it's entirely possible that gcc on Mac doesn't support `__thread`. You need to use `pthread_setspecific` manually.

([This problem has been filed as a bug](http://openradar.appspot.com/6850750).)

Comment: According to Kerrisk in [The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1593272200), you need GCC 3.3 or above for Thread Local Storage (`__thread` on static and global declarations). Mac OS X ships with GCC 4.2, so it looks like Apple removed the functionality (or did not port it way back when). It also requires kernel support (Linux 2.6 and above). which might explain why Apple did not provide it.

Comment: Does this mean that we still can't compile on mac os x (10.10) I have the same issue when trying to install PyMetis (pip install pymetis) and my `gcc --version` reports: `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix` However, I installed gcc v 4.9 using `brew install gcc49`

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your gcc to gcc-4.5 or above (through macports or something). TLS operation on mac is much more expensive than on linux or other unix, because it is emulated.

The following code:

```
__thread int foo;  
void f() {  
  ++foo;  
}
```

on linux, it would be translated to this:

```
f:  
    pushl   %ebp  
    movl    %esp, %ebp  
    movl    %gs:foo@NTPOFF, %eax  
    addl    $1, %eax  
    movl    %eax, %gs:foo@NTPOFF  
    popl    %ebp  
    ret
```

but on mac, it would be translated to this(two function calls!!):

```
_f:  
LFB0:  
    pushq   %rbp  
LCFI0:  
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  
LCFI1:  
    pushq   %rbx  
LCFI2:  
    subq    $8, %rsp  
LCFI3:  
    leaq    ___emutls_v.foo(%rip), %rdi  
    call    ___emutls_get_address  
    movl    (%rax), %eax  
    leal    1(%rax), %ebx  
    leaq    ___emutls_v.foo(%rip), %rdi  
    call    ___emutls_get_address  
    movl    %ebx, (%rax)  
    addq    $8, %rsp  
    popq    %rbx  
    leave  
LCFI4:
    ret
```

Comment: Apple Tech Lab is stupid about this. They say they don't want to waste a register and make it incompatible not realizing that the segment registers have no other use then this anymore. Really sucks. Even if the "__emutls_get_address" is just doing the same single movl instruction. So if anyone is brave enough they can manually code it as assembler inline the way it is done on linux.

By the way, is this a real disassembly? I always thought it is FS which is used for TLS

Comment: you can't "just manually code it" because to use `fs` or `gs` requires the mac kernel to setup the segment base address in the GDT tables.